# Law for type [[a]] -> ([a], [a])

Tags: haskell, free-theorem

I am trying to do this question from my homework:

> Given arbitrary `foo :: [[a]] -> ([a], [a])`, write down one law that the function `foo` satisfies, involving `map` on lists and pairs.

Some context: I am a first year undergrad taking a course of functional programming. Whilst the course is rather introductory, the lecturer has mentioned many things out of syllabus, amongst which are the free theorems. So after attempting to read Wadler's paper, I reckoned that `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` with the law `map f . concat = concat . map (map f)` looks relevant to my problem, since we must have `foo xss = (concat xss, concat' xss)` where `concat` and `concat'` are any functions of type `[[a]] -> [a]`. Then `foo` satisfies `bimap (map f, map g) . foo = \xss -> ((fst . foo . map (map f)) xss, (snd . foo . map (map g)) xss)`.

Already this 'law' seems too long to be correct, and I am unsure of my logic as well. So I thought of using an [online free theorems generator](http://free-theorems.nomeata.de), but I don't get what `lift{(,)}` means:

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES, g :: t1 -> t2.
 forall x :: [[t1]].
  (f x, f (map (map g) x)) in lift{(,)}(map g,map g)

lift{(,)}(map g,map g)
  = {((x1, x2), (y1, y2)) | (map g x1 = y1) && (map g x2 = y2)}
```

How should I understand this output? And how should I derive the law for the function `foo` properly?

Comment: I believe this is saying that `(\(a,b) -> (map f a, map f b)) . foo = foo . map (map f)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `R1` and `R2` are relations (say, `R_i` between `A_i` and `B_i`, with `i in {1,2}`), then `lift{(,)}(R1,R2)` is the "lifted" relations pairs, between `A1 * A2` and `B1 * B2`, with `*` denoting the product (written `(,)` in Haskell).

In the lifed relation, two pairs `(x1,x2) :: A1*A2` and `(y1,y2) :: B1*B2` are related if and only if `x1 R1 y1` and `x2 R2 y2`. In your case, `R1` and `R2` are functions `map g, map g`, so the lifting becomes a function as well: `y1 = map g x1 && y2 = map g x2`.

Hence, the generated

```
(f x, f (map (map g) x)) in lift{(,)}(map g,map g)
```

means:

```
fst (f (map (map g) x)) = map g (fst (f x))
AND
snd (f (map (map g) x)) = map g (snd (f x))
```

or, in other words:

```
f (map (map g) x) = (map g (fst (f x)), map g (snd (f x)))
```

which I wold write as, using `Control.Arrow`:

```
f (map (map g) x) = (map g *** map g) (f x)
```

or even, in pointfree style:

```
f . map (map g) = (map g *** map g) . f
```

This is no surprise, since your `f` can be written as

```
f :: F a -> G a
where F a = [[a]]
      G a = ([a], [a])
```

and `F`,`G` are functors (in Haskell we would need to use a `newtype` to define a functor instance, but I will omit that, since it's irrelevant). In such common case, the free theorem has a very nice form: for every `g`,

```
f . fmap_of_F g = fmap_of_G g . f
```

This is a very nice form, called naturality (`f` can be interpreted as a natural transformation in a suitable category). Note that the two `f`s above are actually instantiated on separate types, so to make types agree with the rest.

In your specific case, since `F a = [[a]]`, it is the composition of the `[]` functor with itself, hence we (unsurprisingly) get `fmap_of_F g = fmap_of_[] (fmap_of_[] g) = map (map g)`.

Instead, `G a = ([a],[a])` is the composition of functors `[]` and `H a = (a,a)` (technically, diagonal functor composed with the product functor). We have `fmap_of_H h = (h *** h) = (\x -> (h x, h x))`, from which `fmap_of_G g = fmap_of_H (fmap_of_[] g) = (map g *** map g)`.

Comment: Nice explanation! Just a question: when you say "for every g", does g have to be total or strict, or are there no restrictions at all?

Comment: @JingjieYANG Yes, there are some restrictions if we use Haskell. Most results like this are actually done in a pure type system where every terminates (hence it is total). In Haskell, if I recall correctly, since we have non termination we need to require `g` total. Similarly, since we have `seq` we need to require `g` to be strict. I'm not 100% sure on the exact restrictions, but I think these should be it. I don't remember where I read about those, though -- probably on the free theorem generator page there's some information.

Comment: Isn't Control.Arrow(***) on tuples a bit out of style, in favor of Data.Bifunctor(bimap)? Any objection to an edit to change to the latter?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I have no idea. I guess it's a bit like `map` vs `fmap`. People continue using `map` since it makes it obvious that we are dealing with lists (and not other functor). Similarly, `(***)` only works on pairs (and not other bifunctors). I'm probably using it mostly for its infix-ness, since in maths we tend to write `f \times g` to apply the product bifunctor. Maybe `bimap` should have its infix variant as well, like `<$>` is a variant for `fmap`.

Comment: While it's true that `(***)` is more specific than `bimap` in that it only works on pairs rather than arbitrary bifunctors, it's also true that `bimap` is more specific than `(***)` in that it only works on functions rather than on arbitrary arrows. Re infix, that wouldn't be quite the same for `bimap` and `fmap`, since `bimap` takes 3 parameters and `fmap` only takes 2.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing as @chi's answer with less ceremony:

*It doesn't matter if you change the `a`s to `b`s before or after the function, you get the same thing (as long as you use an `fmap`-like-thing to do it).*

```
For any f : a -> b,

    [[a]] ------------->   [[b]]
      |    (map.map) f       |
      |                      |
     foo                    foo
      |                      |
      v                      v
    ([a],[a]) ---------> ([b],[b])
              bimap f f

commutes.
```